# Render a react component on a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, webpack

We currently have our website built with Wordpress and I have built a component in React that we want to conditionally render on the page.

I have the component built and bundled with Webpack for production but cannot figure out how to add it to our website and render the component on the page

*edit* I will also need to conditionally render the component (form submit, button click, etc.)

Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've built and bundled your component already, you only need to do three things:

1. Add the bundled JavaScript (the Webpack output) as a script tag in whatever page you want the component to be on (preferably at the bottom of the `<body>`).
   Example: `<script src="wp-content/react/bundle.js"></script>`
2. Add the root element that React will bind to to the same page.
   Example: `<div id="react-root"></div>`
3. In your component file, render the component to the root element.
   Example: `ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('react-root'));`

---

To dynamically show and hide the React component based on something that happens outside the component file, you need to create a way to connect the outside (the DOM) to the inside (React). The easiest way to do this is with a global variable attached to `window`.

In your React component, add the `componentWillMount` method that defines a global variable:

```
componentWillMount() {
    window.showComponent = (option) => {
        // "option" should be true or false
        this.setState({ display: option });
    }
}
```

Based on the value passed to `setState` above, you'll need to add the `display` property to your component's state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        display: false
    };
}
```

Now to make the component show or hide based on the value of `this.state.display` inside the `render()` method:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.display) {
    return (
      ...
    )
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

All that's left to do is use `showComponent(true)` or `showComponent(false)` in your code that handles the form.

Comment: This is great, I managed to get it rendered on my webpage! My only problem now is that I want to only conditionally render it. For example when a user submits a form, it would create the div with id="react-root". However, I get errors  when the script runs but no element with that id exists yet

Comment: It's not possible to dynamically add/remove the React root element since the app binds to it on page load. To do this you'll need to take a few extra steps. I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. What I did was to actually create the root element dynamically on the non-react page and then add the script to the page afterwards

Answer (score 0):

In your React project add the file to the global scope (window) like this:

```
window.myReactComponents = {
  myFirstComponent: () => <MyFirstComponent/>
}
```

Once this is bundled reference the bundlejs file on your non-react page.

In your non react page in the global scope reference ReactDOM.render with the root element which it should use to render like this:

```
window.useComponent = {
  renderMyFirstComponent : ReactDOM.render(
    window.myReactComponents.myFirstComponent(),
    document.getElementById('myReactElement')
  )
};
```

That's it!

[Live example](https://codepen.io/Spizzy/pen/dgbbKZ)

[ReactDOM.render Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)

Comment: Hey thanks, this definitely does work, however for larger bundled components the other answer works a little better. Appreciate the answer though!